# Move rectangle along X axis using checkMouse()

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I would like the rectangle to move where ever I click my mouse, any ideas?
I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. This is for a project where the ball will drop and the rectangle will have to catch the ball. I just need to rectangle to move along the X axis where ever the mouse is clicked

```
from graphics import*
import time
from random import randrange

wd=GraphWin("Catch A Ball",500,500)#size of window
wd.setBackground("lightblue")


p1=220 #size of rectangle # size of rectangle
p2=250


for i in range(1): #outline of rectangle
spt1=Point(p1,480)
spt2=Point(p2,500)
rct=Rectangle(spt1,spt2)
rct.setOutline("black")
rct.setFill("black")
rct.draw(wd)

p=wd.getMouse() # defining the y and x axis 
c=rct.getCenter()
dx=p.getX() - c.getX()
dy=p.getY() - c.getY()
rct.move(dx,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to rectangle to move along the X axis where ever the mouse
>   is clicked

The following rework of your code should do what you describe:

```
from graphics import *

SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500, 500  # size of window

BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT = 30, 20

window = GraphWin("Catch A Ball", SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
window.setBackground("lightblue")

for i in range(1):
    ll = Point(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - BOX_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    ur = Point(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + BOX_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT - BOX_HEIGHT)
    rectangle = Rectangle(ll, ur)  # outline of rectangle
    rectangle.setFill("black")
    rectangle.draw(window)

while True:
    point = window.getMouse()  # obtain cursor position
    center = rectangle.getCenter()
    dx = point.getX() - center.getX()
    rectangle.move(dx, 0)
```

I'm not completely comfortable with the infinite loop `while True` but since Zelle graphics doesn't expose any Tkinter timer events, we'll have make do.